# Mongodb sort concurrency lock

Tags: mongodb, sorting, concurrency, locking

my interrogation is :

If a do a big sort according an indexed value (time to sort is around 5 minutes).
If i have an update (from an user) on the value, it could make problem for the sort. Does Mongo sort an a locked copy of data?

I'have seen that write lock are prioritary on read lock, that means that if i have the first 1000 entries already sorted, if an update makes an entry ( already sorted) the "first one" in the sort instead as exemple the 500th (before)...

```
What will appear in the sorted result :
- The old entry value correctly sorted?
- the new one correctly sorted?  
- the new one not correctly sorted?
```

Thank you!

Comment: It takes 5 minutes to sort the results?

Comment: MongoDB will not actually try and sort all the results on the spot unless it is an in-memory sort, basically `scanAndOrder` is true on the explain

Comment: You are true, i have taken 5mn as an exemple, but yes go threw a btree is quick ... 

The question is now : while updating an index while a sort is done on the index btree : the lock for updating an index will take the priority on the "read lock"? So if the new value would be inserted in the "already sorted" set, this is 'hide' and the sort will give the old value ...

that's it?